# service bus queue disappeared

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We do not know what caused a Service Bus Queue to disappear.  There is no delete action in the Monitor Activity Log.  So when/how was it deleted?

We have since recreated the queue and put a lock on it.  However, we would like to know why/how this happened.

Has anyone experienced this before?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you happen to set a value for [`AutoDeleteOnIdle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.autodeleteonidle?view=azure-dotnet) property of the queue? Without specifying anything, the default should be `TimeSpan.Max`. If it was assigned a custom short value, once the queue went idle for the defined period of time, it would be dropped along with all messages.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, AutoDeleteOnIdle was inadvertently set to 5 minutes.  It would have been good to see a message in the Activity Log indicating how the queue was deleted.

Comment: Scan the code. The default is always `TimeSpan.Max`. The only way to set it to anything else would be custom code/script/manual intervention. Could be that someone was thinking of `MaxLockDuration` (which is 5 mins) and set it accidentally to that value.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your queue to get deleted may be that you would have set the [AutoDeleteOnIdle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.autodeleteonidle?view=azure-dotnet) property.

Another reason might be due to any of your custom code that lead to the deletion of your queue.

**AutoDeleteOnIdle** – This is actually a timespan which denotes how long a queue can stay alive once it is idle before it is automatically deleted. 
By default its value is [TimeSpan.Max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.maxvalue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).The minimum time is 5 mins. If you don't want the queue to be never deleted set it to a maximum value.